# Use sed or rename find series of alphabet then replace with with the same alphabet and a dash -

Tags: bash, sed, rename

I have some images and folders to rename. They are contained in the folder with the same filename as such.

```
/abc123
/abc123/abc123.jpg
```

None of the filenames or folder names have a dash which I want to add after the alphabet. And some of the filenames are already capitalised, but none of the folder names are capitalised. So I want to achieve the following:

From current image name and folder name:

```
abc123.jpg
ABC123.jpg
/abc123
wxyz123456.jpg
/wxyz123456
```

to the desired:

```
ABC-123.jpg
/ABC-123
WXYZ-123456.jpg
/WXYZ-123456
```

I used `rename 's/\(^[a-zA-Z]*\)/$1-/' *.jpg` to rename the images and `rename 's/\(^[a-zA-Z]*\)/$1-/' *` for the folders.

This code is recognising the alphabets in front of the numbers, but I do not know how to output that same pattern space and add a dash after it. I thought either `\1` or `$1` would work, but it didn't.

What am I missing?

Comment: If "none of the folder names are capitalized", what is `/ABC123`?

Comment: Yes, thanks for spotting it.

Comment: Don't you need a * or a + after [a-zA-z]?

Comment: maybe this: `sed -e 's/\([^0-9-]\)\([0-9]\+\)/\1-\2/g'`... something like: `rename 's/([^0-9-])([0-9]+)/$1-$2/g'`

Comment: Thank you for spotting another omission @sureshvv. I've now added the * to `rename 's/\(^[a-zA-Z]*\)/$1-/' *.jpg` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: `rename` is not standard, there are a number of implementations. But if yours uses Perl-compatible regex, you need to remove the backslashes before the parentheses.

Comment: None of this is specific to Bash (the `rename` command doesn't know or care which shell you are using to run it) but tagging this [tag:design-patterns] really takes the cake.